# Counting data from CSV time column in C#

Tags: c#, csv, ado.net

I had make connection with csv file in C# by odbc and getting data properly in my Windows application, but problem is that when I am trying get count of data which is present in column where data is present in format like `4:36:56`.

This contains thousands of data like that. and I am trying to count those data which is greater then `4:30:00` but I am not getting correct count. The code which I am using is:

```
 da = new OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT count(" *") FROM " + filename + " where  " +column name + ">#4:30:00#", con);
 ds = new DataSet();
 da.Fill(ds);
 dt = ds.Tables[0];
 dr = dt.Rows[0];
 label15.Text = dr[0].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Its totally dependant on data type you have used to store value `4:30:00`.

Assuming it to be correct, you can make change in `count(*)` instead of `count("*")` as follows.

Second thing is use of parametrized queries in this case its dynamic.

```
parValue="4:30:00"

cmd=new  Odbccommand("SELECT count(*) FROM " + filename + " where  convert(datetime," +column name + ")>@val", con);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", parValue);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Otherwise simply,

```
da = new OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT count(*) FROM " + filename + " where  {fn convert(" +column name + ",SQL_TIME)>#4:30:00#", con);
```

**Refer this doc for conversions in ODBC:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms715381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Hope Its Helpful.

Comment: in csv file it is in string format and I am treating it as date  time in my application so I am getting problem please help me.please help  me further by odbc or any other way .

Comment: please reply me as soon as possible as I am not getting proper answer from your second option

Comment: @user2279745 It seems you are facing parsing datetime problem, go through my edit

Comment: when I am using your second response iam getting an exception "undefined function convert in expression"

Comment: Go through edit in second option and follow link for conversion in odbc